# What happens to casts using generics - (T)object - at run-time in Java?

Tags: java, class, generics, compiler-construction, casting

As far as I understand, Java Generics erases all the information concerning the parameter type T in the generic method (or in the generic class). That's why we can't use

new expression, such as

```
new T()
```

instanceof expression, such as

```
if(obj instanceof T)
```

inside a generic method.

My question is how the parameter type T works inside a generic method when it comes to casting. For example, I have 3 simple classes here:

```
public class People {

    String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public People(String name) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "People [name=" + name + "]";
    }

}

public class GenericClass<T> {

    public T getCast(People p) {
        return (T)p;
    }
}

public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        People p = new People("Kewei");

        GenericClass<Integer> genericClass = new GenericClass<Integer>();
        Object p_object = genericClass.getCast(p);

        System.out.println(p_object);
    }
}
```

When it executes the `(T)p` in the generic method `getCast(People p)`. Does it just take the type T as Object? or It just removes the whole `(T)` casting at compile time? I've read Bruce Eckel's «Thinking in Java» from which I roughly understand as:

> Java compiler checks at method's entry/leave points at compile time to
>   make sure the internal consistency of generic method, and inserts
>   casting code (at compile time).

Is it the right understanding?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can mentally think of the compiler doing a "re-writing" of the code with generics into code without generics.

In the generic class, T gets erased to the erasure of its upper bound, which in this case is Object, but could be something else. The cast to T becomes a cast to T's upper bound (which in this case is Object, so it is redundant and the compiler might skip it). The method similarly returns T's upper bound (which is Object). So there is no runtime check that the cast is valid inside the method.

```
public class GenericClass {

    public Object getCast(People p) {
        // In this case the cast to T is removed because T's upper bound is Object.
        // But if T's upper bound was, say, Number, then there would still be a cast
        // to the upper bound. e.g. "(Number)p", and the return type would also be Number
        return p;
    }
}
```

In the places that call the method that returns T, the compiler will insert a cast into the actual type of T. In this case, in the main method, you have a `GenericClass<Integer>`, so when `getCast` returns T, it is cast to Integer. So in this case the runtime check now gets "moved" to the calling method, not the method with the cast.

```
// somewhere else
GenericClass genericClass = new GenericClass();
p_object = (Integer)genericClass.getCast(p);
```

It is also possible that the caller kept a `GenericClass<S>` reference (for some type parameter S in its scope), so that the result is cast to S, not a specific type. Then we would repeat the whole re-writing process again (i.e. the cast to S is re-written to a cast to its upper bound, and places that call into that method will cast the result to their actual type argument). This means that the runtime check might be deferred to yet another place, and so on.

Comment: +1 And that's why `ClassCastException`s caused by heap pollution are harder to debug - because their stacktraces don't point to the actual bug, but the place where the compiler happened to insert a cast.

Comment: I think you mean upper bound, not lower bound. Also, it's the erasure of the upper bound, which is the erasure of the left most element of the upper bound.

Comment: Thank you very much @newacct, for your explanation. As you said, **In the places that call the method that returns T, the compiler will insert a cast into the actual type of T. In this case, in the main method, you have a GenericClass<Integer>, so when getCast returns T, it is cast to Integer.** But in any case, for my method `T getCast(People p)`, an instance of `People` can't be casted into `Integer`, I don't understand how come my code works "magically". Why it doesn't throw an `ClassCastException`? It seems that the `p` (instance of `People`) was never ever casted into `Integer`. Why?

Comment: @keweishang: I'm not sure, but I'm guessing it might have to do with it being assigned to a variable of type `Object`. If you change it to `Integer p_object` does it make a difference?

Comment: @newacct if I change the call of the generic method to `Object p_object = (Integer)genericClass.getCast(p);`, it gives an `ClassCastException: com.foo.People cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer`. Theoretically, the compiler should itself insert automatically a cast into the actual type of `T` (in this case, `Integer`) for the method `genericClass.getCast(p)` at compile-time.

Comment: To this point, I still have 2 questions: **1**, inside the body a generic method who returns T, what type does it return, the upper bound of T or Object? **2**. Just right after the call to a generic method who returns T, what the compiler will add as cast? Does the compiler **always** add a the actual type of T, **or** it depends on the type of object to whom the reference is given?

Comment: @keweishang: 1. it returns whatever T is erased to, which in this case is Object. 2. A cast is necessary if the type that is returned (the erasure) is not assignable to the type of whatever you are assigning or passing that value to. In this case you are assigning it to a variable of type Object, in which case a cast is not *necessary*, and it seems that the compiler does not insert a cast. However, it would not be incorrect for some other compiler to insert a cast in that case too.

Comment: Yes, your explanation makes sense! I think you're right! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score -1):

Java never casts anything; at run time it's simply treated "as an object".
The JRE attempts to call methods on that object, and since they've been proven to exists at compile it, it works.

There's **no reference** to what class T is at runtime. **None**.  So no casting is done.

Comment: Not true. Casts to normal classes are also checked at runtime

Comment: We do still need checks for the casts and assignments though. i.e. `List<String> list; String s = list.get(0);` will have a dynamic check if the object really is a string. That's a predictable `ld/cmp/br` sequence though (i.e. a single cycle if we don't miss to memory).

Comment: Yes, I meant the Generic class itself cas no reference to T and does no casts.  Very poorly written reponse on my part.